# JS: input field and dropdown option change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building my own dropdown options with input field as below:

```
<input class="search" type="text">
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="option" data-options="1">1</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="2">2</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="3">3</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="4">4</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="5">5</div>
</div>
```

[image]

I am little baffled with two functions:

**1.** When you are in the "input" field, I want to be able to use arrow keyboard button (down or up button) to select one of the options (option css change like `.option:hover{background:black; color:white;}`and **2.** show in the input field as you press the arrow button on the keyboard.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to write something? Is there a specific reason you build your own and not use some lib for that? [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) for example, combined with regular input

Comment: I might look into the jquery-ui for this. Thank you. And I am trying to use `input` field as a part of the `selection` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if it's ok click into the input and use key arrow up and down for navigate.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 window.displayBoxIndex = -1;

 $("#search").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {  Navigate(1); }
  if(e.keyCode==38) { Navigate(-1); }
 });
                   
 var Navigate = function(diff) {
  $('#search').val('');
  displayBoxIndex += diff;
  var oBoxCollection = $(".option");
  if (displayBoxIndex >= oBoxCollection.length) {
   displayBoxIndex = 0;   
  }
  if (displayBoxIndex < 0) {
   displayBoxIndex = oBoxCollection.length - 1;
  }
  var cssClass = "option_box_hover";
  oBoxCollection.removeClass(cssClass).eq(displayBoxIndex).addClass(cssClass);
  var optionsel = $(".option_box_hover").attr('data-options');
  $('#search').val(optionsel);
 }
 

});
```

```css
.option_box_hover, .option_box:hover
{
  background:black;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" class="search" type="text">
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="option" data-options="1">1</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="2">2</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="3">3</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="4">4</div>
  <div class="option" data-options="5">5</div>
</div>
```

cheers!!